# Nativescript app fails to build after including platform.js

Tags: android, nativescript

I have a Nativscript 5.0 app that needs access to platform info (device, screen). I added the tns core module platform.js and then I rebuilt the whole project with 'tns run android'.

Now I'm getting this error:

```
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContentResolver' of undefined
tns_modules/tns-core-modules/platform/platform.js', line: 79, column: 83
```

This error refers to this code in platform.android.js:

```
Object.defineProperty(Device.prototype, "uuid", {
        get: function () {
            if (!this._uuid) {
                var nativeApp = appModule.android.nativeApp;
                this._uuid = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(nativeApp.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            }
            return this._uuid;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
```

Specifically, nativeApp seems to be undefined. I'm running this code thru an Android simulator. What am I missing here? do I need to define the OS explicitly somewhere to prevent this error?

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly you are loading the platform module in your code?

Comment: Does it really matter? I'm loading it in a src/app/utilities/utils.ts file as such:
const platform = require("tns-core-modules/platform");

Comment: Generally it doesn't. I use platforms module in every app and never hit this issue. So I'm just wondering whether you are accessing the module too early, before the app is ready.
Which flavour you are using for development (JS / TS / Angular / Vue)?

Comment: @Manoj you're absolutely right. I was requiring the utils class at the top and loading the device info in ngOnInit(), which is apparently too early (the require statement). Moving the require down to a function resolved the error. Please add your comment as an answer so you get the upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, thanks for confirming it worked. Added the same as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be accessing the platform module too early, even before the `nativeApp` instance is fully initialised and ready to be used.

You may wait until the `displayed` / `activityCreated` event Or simply the `loaded` event of any component, which ensures that the `nativeApp` will be ready.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when trying to get `device.uuid`. I managed to get it work by using `launchEvent`:

```js
import { on as applicationOn, launchEvent } from 'tns-core-modules/application'
import { device } from 'tns-core-modules/platform'

applicationOn(launchEvent, () => {
    // Use device.uuid here
})
```